# merge two data.frames and replace values of certain columns of df1 with values of df2

Tags: r, replace, merge, tm

i have two data.frames that i want to merge and replace values of certain columns of df1
with values of df2. in this working example there are only 3 columns. but in the original data, 
there are about 20 columns that should remain in the final data.frame.

```
NO <- c(2, 4, 7, 18, 25, 36, 48)
WORD <- c("apple", "peach", "plum", "orange", "grape", "berry", "pear")
CLASS <- c("p", "x", "x", "n", "x", "p", "n")
ColA <- c("hot", "warm", "sunny", "rainy", "windy", "cloudy", "snow")
df1 <- data.frame(NO, WORD, CLASS, ColA)
df1

#   NO   WORD CLASS   ColA
# 1  2  apple     p    hot
# 2  4  peach     x   warm
# 3  7   plum     x  sunny
# 4 18 orange     n  rainy
# 5 25  grape     x  windy
# 6 36  berry     p cloudy
# 7 48   pear     n   snow

NO <- c(4, 18, 36)
WORD <- c("patricia", "oliver", "bob")
CLASS <- c("p", "n", "x")

df2 <- data.frame(NO, WORD, CLASS)
df2

#   NO     WORD CLASS
# 1  4 patricia     p
# 2 18   oliver     n
# 3 36      bob     x
```

i want to merge the two data.frames and replace the values of WORD and CLASS from df1
with the values of WORD and CLASS from df2

my data.frame should look like this:

```
#   NO      WORD CLASS   ColA
# 1  2     apple     p    hot
# 2  4  patricia     p   warm
# 3  7      plum     x  sunny
# 4 18    oliver     n  rainy
# 5 25     grape     x  windy
# 6 36       bob     x cloudy
# 7 48      pear     n   snow
```

Comment: this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417517/merge-almost-identical-rows-filtering-nas-and-shorter-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
auxind<-match(df2$NO, df1$NO)  # Stores the repeated rows in df1
dfuni<-(rbind(df1[,1:3],df2)[-auxind,])  # Merges both data.frames and erases the repeated rows from the first three colums of df1
dfuni<-dfuni[order(dfuni$NO),] # Sorts the new data.frame
df1[,1:3]<-dfuni
```

Comment: the problem is, i have 20 columns in df1 but only three columns in df2 so i get an error because of differing number of columns! do you know how i can fix that?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Now you work just with the first three colums and then substitute them in the original `df1`.

Comment: well it seemed to work, but on the same dataset with "NA" values i get the error: Error in xj[i] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts! what does this mean?

Comment: I'm not sure. Could you provide an example that generates this error?

Comment: i fixed the problem! thank you! it had something to do with factors! if i added stringsAsFactors = FALSE it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This approach could work as well though is more playing around than the best answer to the question:

```
library(qdap); library(qdapTools)
df1[, 2] <- as.character(df1[, 2])
trms <- strsplit(df1[, 1] %lc% colpaste2df(df2, 2:3, keep.orig = FALSE), "\\.")
df1[sapply(trms, function(x) !all(is.na(x))), 2:3] <- 
    do.call(rbind, trms[sapply(trms, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))])
```